# Vue variables not reactive in children of extended TypeScript parent class

Tags: typescript, class, vue.js

I very recently started playing around with TypeScript on my Vue.js projects. For my current project (a very simple chat application) I have created a TypeScript class called `ChatParent.ts`. It contains all methods and variables necessary for sending/receiving messages. I extend this class in my other components. Calling the parent methods from these child class works fine, however, when I monitor a variable in the parent class (e.g., `username`) the change is not reflected in the DOM of the child component.

I have tried adding setter/getter methods and computed properties (e.g., `get methodName(): boolean`), neither of which works.

The code below is from `ChatParent.ts` and has been simplified.

```
@Component({
    name: "ChatParent",
})
 export default class ChatParent extends Vue {
    private chatClient: new ChatClient(...);
    subscribed: boolean = false;

    username: string = "";

    subscribe() {
        const subscriptionRequest = new SubscriptionRequest();
        subscriptionRequest.setUsername(username);

        this.chatClient.subscribe(subscriptionRequest).on("data", data => {
            this.subscribed = true;
        });
    }
    ...
}
```

The following is from `TypeBox.vue`.

```
<template>
    <v-container pa-2>
        <v-textarea
                outline
                label="Type message here..."
                :disabled="!subscribed"
                v-model="message"
        ></v-textarea>
    </v-container>

</template>

<script lang="ts">
    import {Component} from "vue-property-decorator";
    import ChatParent from "@/components/ChatParent.ts";

    @Component({
        name: "TypeBox",
    })
    export default class TypeBox extends ChatParent {
        message : string = "";
    }
</script>
```

Whenever the `data` callback is called in the `subscribe(...)` method, the subscription variable gets updated in the parent class, but the change is not reflected in the child component (where it is supposed to enable the text area if the `subscribe` variable is true).

I think that my understanding of Vue + TypeScript is perhaps completely incorrect (with regards to extending classes). I would, therefore, really appreciate some insight.

Comment: It's only rendered once, you would need to force a rerender for it to update, the best way imo is to give the child a key and change the key when the parent updates that will force the child to rerender. see here on that: 
https://michaelnthiessen.com/force-re-render

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I did not understand the use of extending classes in Vue/TypeScript correctly. The variable data is not shared amongst all classes that extend the parent class (`ChatParent`), which is why the variables did not trigger DOM changes.

I solved this problem by using Vuex as follows:

```
  class ChatModule extends VuexModule {
  // Variables
  chatClient!: ChatClient;
  subscribed: boolean = false;
  username: string = "";
  messages: string = "";

  // Getters
  get getUsername(): string {
    return this.username;
  }

  get getMessages(): string {
    return this.messages;
  }

  get isSubscribed(): boolean {
    return this.subscribed;
  }

  // Mutations and Actions 
  ...

  export default getModule(ChatModule);
}
```

The Vuex store contains all the variables. The `TypeBox.vue` component now simply extends `Vue` and calls store actions/getters:

```
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from "vue-property-decorator";
import chat from "@/store/modules/chat";
@Component({
  name: "TypeBox"
})
export default class TypeBox extends Vue {
  private message: string = "";
  clearMessage(): void {
    this.message = "";
  }
  sendMessage(message: string): void {
    chat.sendMessage(message);
  }
  get isSubscribed(): boolean {
    return chat.isSubscribed;
  }
}
</script>
```

The Vuex store actions/getters/mutations can be made Type Safe by using the `vuex-module-decorators` npm module.

For more details, [see my GitHub repository](https://github.com/angelomelonas/grpc-spring-boot-vue-chat/blob/master/frontend/src/store/modules/chat.ts).

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that some data from one of your classes may be undefined .In that case your data won't be reactive (see: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component#undefined-will-not-be-reactive ) . you could try to use this syntax e.g `username: string = null!`